# Using contains inside of where returns empty?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to troubleshoot a EF query that is probably more of a LINQ question.  Using contains inside of where like this (using linqpad to test with).

The query below I get an empty result, even though I know `retval` has the results I am interested in.

Query #1

```
var retval = (from a in DeliveryOrders 
              join b in CustomerOrders on a.CustomerOrderID equals b.ID 
              where b.OrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)
              select a).ToList();

var retval2 = retval.Where (r => r.DeliveryOrderNo.Contains("hd")).ToList();

retval2.Dump();
```

If I use the where in the first query like so, I get the results I expect.

Query #2

```
var retval = (from a in DeliveryOrders 
              join b in CustomerOrders on a.CustomerOrderID equals b.ID 
              where b.OrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)    
                    && a.DeliveryOrderNo.Contains("hd")
              select a).ToList();
```

Why does the first result return empty but the 2nd return what I expect?
After trying a few different things, it seems to an issue of case sensitivity.

Am I correct to say that In query #1, the contains method is being used against a .net collection, whereas with query #2, the contains method gets translated to SQL and so that might explain the case-sensitive difference?

**[update]**
I can confirm now, that its a case issue because one is being translated to sql, but in the other is .net which is case sensitive with strings.

Comment: does your first query result has deliveryOrderNo "hd"?

Comment: Yes, in Query #1, retval contains DeliveyrOrderNo "hd", but retval2 is empty.  If instead in Query #1, I set retval2 to use Contains("HD"), I get my expected results for retval2.    So as I mentioned, I think the difference is that in one case the Contains method is being translated to SQL, where the other its simply working against a .Net collection and so then the case sensitivity.

Comment: @bitshift your SQL Server is probably case insensitive (default) and as you correctly point our .Net is Case Sensitive, you could use ToUpper() or ToLower() to compare in a case insensitive manner.

Comment: @bitshift , at this point i would think, its not the database which is causing the issue, it would be the linq query on the list